# Collections.sort() not sorting single digit number

Tags: java, android, sorting, comparable

This is my data set `[B,A,D,C,3,10,1,2,11,14]`

I want to sort it like this `[1,2,3,10,11,14,A,B,C,D]`

When i use following

```
public class ArenaModel implements Comparable<ArenaModel>{

    private String sectionName;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ArenaModel o) {
        return sectionName.compareTo(o.sectionName);
    }
```

In Main class, i do following.

```
 Collections.sort(arenaArrayList);
```

It does sorting but single digit numbers do not get sort, and i get following result.

```
[10,11,14,1,2,3,A,B,C,D]
```

Comment: Yes, sorting as strings gives a different result from sorting as numbers. You can write a custom comparator that does the right thing.

Comment: as @OleV.V. has said, TECHNICALLY it is sorting single digit numbers, just not in the way you were hoping it would.

Comment: Are these all stored as String?

Comment: @AshvinSharma: Yes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public class ArenaModel implements Comparable<ArenaModel>{

        private String sectionName;

        @Override
        public int compareTo(ArenaModel o) {
            try {
                Integer s1 = Integer.valueOf(sectionName);
                Integer s2 = Integer.valueOf(o.sectionName);
                return s1.compareTo(s2);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Not an integer
            }
            return sectionName.compareTo(o.sectionName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Relying on exceptions may be costly operation on big data. Instead use regexp matcher or third-party libraries such as  Apache and etc.

Comment: It doesn't handle cases of  a number compared to a character and the reverse way correctly.             `return sectionName.compareTo(o.sectionName);` will not work in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the String contains no mixed values :  characters and digits, you could do that :

```
import static java.lang.Character.isAlphabetic;
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

@Override
public int compareTo(ArenaModel o) {
    String sectionOther = o.getSectionName();
    String sectionThis = getSectionName();

    // 1) handle comparisons with any alphabetic value
    boolean isThisAlphabetic = isAlphabetic(sectionThis);
    boolean isOtherAlphabetic = isAlphabetic(sectionOther);

    // move the alphabet value at the end
    if (isThisAlphabetic && !isOtherAlphabetic){
       return 1;
    }

    // move the alphabet value at the end
    if (!isThisAlphabetic && isOtherAlphabetic){
       return -1;
    }

    // compare String values
    if (isThisAlphabetic && isOtherAlphabetic){
       return sectionThis.compareTo(sectionOther);
    }

    // 2) By eliminatation, you have two integer values
    return Integer.compare(parseInt(sectionThis), parseInt(sectionOther));
}
```